# Extracting tile image from HTML content

Tags: javascript

I want to show the logo of the webpage when user enter any url and for that purpose I am able to get the HTML content of the page using request library of node.js but can anyone guide me to find the image that we see in the browser tab when we open that website.
[Image I want to fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xKtR.png)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. A logo on a website can be anything including the website's company logo, which will be fetched differently on every website. Please specify with examples and such

Comment: I want to fetch an image that we see in tab of the browser when we open the website.

Comment: Maybe take a screenshot and put an arrow on what image you want to fetch, and upload it to your question?

Comment: Maybe "<img src='http://example.com/favicon.ico' />" (Where does that ";" come from?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it really depends on how the website configured their favicon.

If you are requesting the HTML you would then need to be able to parse it with something that is forgiving, as you don't control the quality of these pages. Something like [HTMLParser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2) would work.

In the method you create you will need to look for a few tags and stop when you find the first match:

Here is an example of what you would be looking for, this list is by no means exhaustive:

```
<!-- Favicon -->
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/favicons/tile.png"> <!-- Windows 8 -->
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#00CCFF"/> <!-- Windows 8 color -->
<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicons/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicons/favicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed-144x144.png"><!-- iPad Retina-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed-114x114.png"><!--iPhone Retina -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed-72x72.png"><!-- iPad 1 e 2 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed-57x57.png"><!-- iPhone, iPod e Android 2.2+ -->
```

As you can see there are many options. However, you may be able to simplify your code by checking if a favicon.png or favicon.ico exists in the root of the domain before event parsing the HTML.

Example http://www.cnn.com/favicon.ico

Comment: Thanks it is of great help,  Got the idea to extract image